# Laravel 8 removing qoute on the sql

Tags: sql, laravel

Hi i just wanna know if what i did wrong

this my function

```
public function fetchJobs(Request $request){
    $id = (int)$request->input("id");

    $jobs = DB::table('job')
    ->select('job.*')
    ->where('job.status', '=', 0)
    ->Where('application.applicant','=' ,null)
    ->leftJoin('application', function($join) use ($id)
    {
        $join->on('application.job', '=', 'job.id');
        $join->on('application.applicant','=',$id);
    })
    ->toSql();
    return $jobs;
}
```

this is the result

```
select `job`.* from `job` 
left join `application` on `application`.`job` = `job`.`id` and `application`.`applicant` = `39` 
where `job`.`status` = 0 and `application`.`applicant` is null
```

the error of is that 39 has qoutes is there a way to remove the qoute?

Comment: What SQL driver are you using - MySQL? Postgres? - and what is the exact error you're getting? Laravel should handle this automatically already.

Comment: hi thanks for the response im using MySql and i receive this error     "message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '39' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `job`.* from `job` left join `application` on `application`.`job` = `job`.`id` and `application`.`applicant` = `39` where `job`.`status` = 0 and `application`.`applicant` is null)",

Comment: `$join->on('application.applicant','=',$id);` probably needs to be `$join->where('application.applicant','=',$id);`. Might also need to be moved out into the main query, I'm not certain.

Comment: okay ill try it

Comment: HI thanks a lot for the response i solved it by adding DB::raw()

Comment: I don't know that that's really the best way to handle this, but OK. You're doing a `JOIN` where you want a `WHERE`; doing it the right way will save you from future updates that might break this.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this by adding DB:raw()

```
public function fetchJobs(Request $request){
    $id = (int)$request->input("id");

    $jobs = DB::table('job')
    ->select('job.*')
    ->where('job.status', '=', 0)
    ->Where('application.applicant','=' ,null)
    ->leftJoin('application', function($join) use ($id)
    {
        $join->on('application.job', '=', 'job.id');
        $join->on('application.applicant','=',DB::raw($id));
    })
    ->get();
    return $jobs;
}
```